# Callback con Kotlin y comunicación de Actividad a Fragmento

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, callback

Tengo una aplicación sencilla para hacer pruebas, ya que estoy practicando Kotlin. Tiene una "actividad básica" que trae Android Studio por defecto. También se muestra un fragmento de mapas de Google en la actividad básica (el código está al final del post).

Como todos sabéis, la actividad básica tiene un botón flotante como este:
[image: Botón flotante]

El principal problema es que aún no conozco las particularidades de Kotlin y tampoco que tampoco he trabajado mucho con fragmentos, pero lo que quiero hacer es eso: haciendo clic en el botón flotante, el mapa se "reinicia", recargando nuevamente y limpiándolo de marcadores que haya colocado el usuario.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de implementar esto? Mi intención era hacerlo con un callback con interfaces anonimas, pero no logro que me salga bien. Tampoco cosigo tener acceso a los métodos de la instancia de FMaps que corresponde al fragmento, por lo que no puedo, por ejemplo, pasarle la interfaz instanciada por parametro.

Dejo a continuación todo el código limpio de la app, y espero sugerencias:

**Actividad principal** - "Basic activity" por defecto

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->

    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Fragmento del mapa** - Fragmento de mapa generado por defecto

```
class FMaps : Fragment() {

    private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_maps, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo limpiaría los markers en el fragment del mapa, no en la activity... porque imagínate que en lugar de un fragment tengas 20 para la misma activity, ¿debe esta activity hacer toda la lógica? Sería inmantenible.